# What does Eclipse do with the "Project References" checked projects?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, project-reference

Right click on a project-> properties -> Project References.
A list of the projects in your workspace appears for you to check.

If it only does what I think (force a rebuild when you want to build/run and the referenced project is updated), shouldn't ADT plugin check it when you add a project as a library in Properties->Android? Should I suggest that feature? If so, where?